# Efficiently serialising timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe to analyse that has a column of dates as datetimes, and a column of hours as integers.

I would like to combine the two columns into a single timestamp field for some further analysis, but cannot find a way to do so quickly.

I have this code that works, but takes an inoordinate amount of time due to the length of the dataframe (~1m entries)

```
for i in range(len(my_df))
    my_df['gen_timestamp'][i] = datetime.datetime.combine(my_df['date'][i],
                                                          datetime.time(my_df['hour'][i])
```

What I would like to do is to somehow convert the datetime type in my_df['date'] to an integer (say a timestamp in seconds) and the integer type in my_df['hour'], so that they can be quickly summed without the need for a laborious loop.

Worst case I then convert that integer back to a datetime in one go or just use seconds as my data type going forwards.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can construct a TimedeltaIndex and add this to your datetimes:

```
In [112]:
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2017,1,1), periods=10), 'hour':np.arange(10)})
df

Out[112]:
        date  hour
0 2017-01-01     0
1 2017-01-02     1
2 2017-01-03     2
3 2017-01-04     3
4 2017-01-05     4
5 2017-01-06     5
6 2017-01-07     6
7 2017-01-08     7
8 2017-01-09     8
9 2017-01-10     9

In [113]:
df['timestamp'] = df['date'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['hour'], unit='h')
df

Out[113]:
        date  hour           timestamp
0 2017-01-01     0 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1 2017-01-02     1 2017-01-02 01:00:00
2 2017-01-03     2 2017-01-03 02:00:00
3 2017-01-04     3 2017-01-04 03:00:00
4 2017-01-05     4 2017-01-05 04:00:00
5 2017-01-06     5 2017-01-06 05:00:00
6 2017-01-07     6 2017-01-07 06:00:00
7 2017-01-08     7 2017-01-08 07:00:00
8 2017-01-09     8 2017-01-09 08:00:00
9 2017-01-10     9 2017-01-10 09:00:00
```

So in your case I expect the following to work:

```
my_df['gen_timestamp'] = my_df['date'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex(my_df['hour'], unit='h')
```

this assumes that `my_df['date']` is already `Datetime` if not convert first using `my_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'])`